# Can I trigger event receiver when webpart is added?

Tags: web-part, event-receivers

Is there such an event receiver, that would fire when user adds webpart to a page? 
If yes, how can I create such receiver?

Comment: I think we need some additional details regarding what you are trying to accomplish. Could you add a little more about what you are expecting to happen and how?

Answer (score 0):

Could you perhaps use the [OnWebpartAdded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.spwebpartmanager.onwebpartadded.aspx) method to accomplish what you need to?